# Install KDE applications under Gnome?

Tags: gnome, kde

I try my best not to install KDE applications on Gnome of my Ubuntu, but sometimes I have to install some KDE applications such as Okular. Moreover, sometimes I have to install from their source of their latest release, which I often fail to do.

I wonder how Gnome support KDE applications?

How shall I install an KDE application properly in Gnome?

For example, to install latest Okular from source in Ubuntu Gnome, I follow [here](http://okular.kde.org/download.php):

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/okular
cd okular
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/kde4/install/dir ..
make
make install
```

Updated: When I reach the command `cmake`, I find that  `CMakeLists.txt` is in `/tmp/okular/`, so I specify `../` to `cmake`:

```
/tmp/okular/build$ sudo cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin
```

The output is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/new. There is no executable `okular` in `/usr/bin`.

I wonder how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you not using your distribution's package manager to install them? You need KDE dependencies.

Comment: Because I need a version higher than the one default in my package manager.

Answer (score 4):

> how Gnome support KDE applications?

I don't know if it "supports" them in an active way, but there's probably no reason you can't use them inside GNOME anyway.  Many of them should not require KDE to be the running desktop environment, and GNOME won't care.

> How shall I install an KDE application properly in Gnome?

With `apt`, or whatever package management system you usually use: `apt-cache search okular`.  If that doesn't work, try `dpkg -S "*okular*"`.

> Moreover, sometimes I have to install from their source of their latest release, which I often fail to do.

Unless you have a particular reason to do this, just use the available ububtu packages.  If you are doing it to avoid pulling in a lot of other KDE stuff, that is a bad reason because:

- It is just disk space, probably not more than a few dozen MB.  Or so.
- You probably won't get around this in the end anyway, as we shall see.

> to install latest Okular from source in Ubuntu Gnome, I follow:

Part of those instructions are to first *[build KDE itself](http://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/KDE4)*.  If you haven't done this, you may have some problems can not be covered by just installing KDE from `apt`.  For example, it may require the source be available, and if there is some particular reason you want this git repo version of okular, it may depend on the git repo version of KDE.

However, you could first at least try by installing the ubuntu packages.  If that doesn't work, just remove them and build from source.

> I don't know how to specify -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

As per the example on the page you linked, that should be the path where you installed the KDE you built.  It looks like it has some defaults that include
`/usr/share/kde4/apps`, which would probably exist if you try with the ubuntu packages.  The exact file you'd need would be:

```
   /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake
```

Which is could be part of a KDE `-dev` package.  `dpkg -S FindKDE4Internal.cmake` may help, although it failed on the ubuntu install I had access to.  Since the explicit recommendation for building okular this way is to have a parallel build of KDE on the system, it may not be in *any* ubuntu package, in which case you have to build KDE from source first.

Comment: Cmake is looking for a `FindKDE4Internal` module in that directory (that it will use to find the libs and includes). It probably is in some kde*-dev package.

Comment: @Leiaz Thx for catching this.  I should have mentioned the dev packages, also. I've edited the last few paragraphs to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! How shall specify `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/kde4/install/dir ..`?

Comment: Use an appropriate value for `/path/to/your/kde4/install/dir`.

Comment: I updated my post with a new problem. I ran `sudo cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin`
The output is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/new. There is no executable `okular` in `/usr/bin`. I think I do something wrong again?

Comment: The output is pretty explicit ("libkexiv2 is not installed", "libspectre is not installed", etc.), and mostly refers back to the prereqs mentioned in the instructions.  **Note you will need the `-dev` version of those installed.**  `apt-cache search libkexiv2` (e.g.) will help you find them.

Comment: @Tim cmake doesn't compile anything. cmake generate the Makefiles, you then have to run make (and make install to copy in the install dir). It seems cmake completed and the missing libraries are optional (you may still want to install some of them).