# Problem installing Okular from ppa under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kde, okular

Under Ubuntu 12.04, I installed [Okular from a ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kalakris/+archive/okular).

After I installed it, I ran into the following problem of opening a PDF file:

```
$ okular my.pdf
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-5dWEZJSTX0,guid=4834397efeb7eb0cb8c1da4300000038"
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-5dWEZJSTX0,guid=4834397efeb7eb0cb8c1da4300000038"
Registered DEC:  true
okular(15329)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(15329)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(15329)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(15329)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(15329)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
Registered event listener change listener:  true
okular: symbol lookup error: okular: undefined symbol: _ZN11KActivities16ResourceInstanceC1EmP7QObject
```

Here is more information about the installed Okular:

```
$ okular --version
Qt: 4.8.1
KDE Development Platform: 4.8.5 (4.8.5)
Okular: 0.17.2

$ ldd $(which okular)
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7773000)
    libkparts.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkparts.so.4 (0xb7707000)
    libkactivities.so.6 => /usr/lib/libkactivities.so.6 (0xb76f1000)
    libkio.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkio.so.5 (0xb7443000)
    libkdeui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5 (0xb7000000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xb652d000)
    libkdecore.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdecore.so.5 (0xb625c000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xb5f7f000)
    libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtDBus.so.4 (0xb5efe000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb5e19000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb5c6f000)
    libnepomuk.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomuk.so.4 (0xb5b8b000)
    libnepomukutils.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukutils.so.4 (0xb5b53000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0xb5b10000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0xb59c3000)
    libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4 (0xb596e000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb583a000)
    libstreamanalyzer.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0 (0xb57bc000)
    libsolid.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsolid.so.4 (0xb56d9000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0xb56d0000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0xb56ca000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb56c0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb5694000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb5675000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xb566c000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xb5652000)
    libattica.so.0.3 => /usr/lib/libattica.so.0.3 (0xb5567000)
    libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 (0xb5533000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb54fe000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb54e3000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xb54ca000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb53d1000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb53a7000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb5390000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb52f6000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb52a7000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xb5296000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb5284000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0xb5272000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xb524b000)
    libdlrestrictions.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdlrestrictions.so.1 (0xb5246000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb5241000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb5238000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7774000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xb51ee000)
    libsoprano.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsoprano.so.4 (0xb50fa000)
    libsopranoclient.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsopranoclient.so.1 (0xb50a9000)
    libnepomukquery.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukquery.so.4 (0xb505d000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb503c000)
    libstreams.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreams.so.0 (0xb5004000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xb4eb7000)
    libudev.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 (0xb4ea7000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xb4ea1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb4e77000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xb4e1a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb4e16000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb4dda000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb4dd3000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb4dcb000)
```

The output of `less /var/log/apt/history.log` is in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/history.log, and the relevant part is:

```
Start-Date: 2014-04-05  09:56:11
Commandline: apt-get install okular
Install: libkactivities6:i386 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libpoppler28:i386 (0.20.5-1ubuntu3~precise1~ppa1, automatic), libkactivities-bin:i386 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1, automatic), libpoppler-qt4-4:i386 (0.20.5-1ubuntu3~precise1~ppa1, automatic), libokularcore3:i386 (4.11.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04~ppa2, automatic)
Upgrade: okular:i386 (4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1, 4.11.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.04~ppa2)
End-Date: 2014-04-05  09:56:42
```

What is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: Definitely looks like `okular` or one of its dependencies needs a slightly different version of some library other than what you have on your system. Trouble is that there are loads of them. Have you also installed all the poppler dependencies from the `ppa` (they may not all have been pulled by default).

Comment: You can check by looking at `less /var/log/apt/history.log` (or add the relevant part if you are not sure). If not a simple `apt-get upgrade` *may* fix the issue.

Comment: @Graeme: `sudo apt-get install poppler` says `E: Unable to locate package poppler`. But the ppa https://launchpad.net/~kalakris/+archive/okular?field.series_filter=precise has both okular and poppler, and I have added the ppa by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kalakris/okular`.

Comment: Put further information in the question, not in comments. Also, you might have more success reporting this to the person who made the PPA.

Comment: Suggestion: try rebuilding the packages on your system. There may be some minor difference in the package the PPA is using, and what you have on your system. Rebuilding usually increases the chances on the package working on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poster successfully rebuilt the Okular PPA sources on his system. Some versions of the build dependencies were not quite correct for his system, so he had to adjust them. It is unclear why this was necessary, since the posters system is Precise and so is the PPA.

@Graeme and I walked him through the process in the unix.sx chat room.
The transcript of the chat session starts at
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14710296#14710296

@Graeme suggests that people facing a similar problem look at
[Kubuntu Backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports/+index?field.series_filter=precise)
in the first instance. These are more "official" PPAs.

Comment: For kubuntu backports, is it the same for Ubuntu ppa? I.e. download source code from there, and unpack and install with the same commands? Are applications from Ubuntu ppa more adapted to Ubuntu than applications from Kubuntu backports?

Comment: @Tim My general recommendation for anything that is not specifically built on your exact same platform - same Os, same version, it to rebuild it if possible. I have no specific information about using Kubuntu PPAs on Ubuntu.

Comment: hi, Faheem. I recently ran into problem with the installed Okular http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125860/okular-doesnt-work-any-more

Answer (score 2):

Definitely looks like you have everything from the ppa that you need (sometimes you may not if the dependencies aren't versioned correctly). Grepping my own system, it seems the missing symbol is in `libkactivities6`. There is no versioned dependency here so I can't tell which one it is built against.

I would check to see what other versions of the package are available, it could simply be that there is a newer one and all you need to do is install it. Either that or it is built against an older one, which you could just downgrade to, but be aware that updates in Ubuntu are usually security or bug fixes. To check:

```
sudo apt-get update  # make sure everything downloads ok and repeat if not
apt-cache show libkactivities6
```

To install a particular version, just add `=version` to the package name in `apt-get`. Eg, to install the version you already have:

```
sudo apt-get install libkactivities6=4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1
```

Failing this, as per [@Faheem Mitha's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123272/problem-when-installing-okular-from-ppa-under-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment195417_123272), your only option to install the package is to rebuild it.

#### Update

Looking at your `apt-cache` output, you do have 2 versions of libkactivities6. Checking on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libkactivities6&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all) I see the older of the two is the current 12.10 version. The other one must have came from somewhere else (another ppa perhaps/).

If you do (note I originally missed the `4:` above):

```
sudo apt-get install libkactivities6=4:4.8.2-0ubuntu2
```

it should fix *this* issue, **but** it may cause a problem with whatever other program the newer version was installed for. It may also be that `apt` will refuse to do the downgrade because of this.

Rebuilding the ppa package which is otherwise configured to play nicley with Ubuntu, as opposed to building the vanilla `okular` source from upstream is probably the best solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. I have apt-get updated. but `E: Version '4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1' for 'libkactivities6' was not found`. The version of my current `libkactivities6` is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1

Comment: Well that's odd, this is the version you *already have*. You may need to do `libkactivities6:1386=4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1`, installing this *won't do anything*. You need to see which *other* versions are available. If you are unsure, please post the output of `apt-cache show libkactivities`

Comment: Actually, the first thing I would do is rebuild the package(s). It wouldn't be a last resort. :-) It's free software, people. You have the source.

Comment: The output of `sudo apt-cache show libkactivities` is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/tmp

Comment: @FaheemMitha probably right, this could well be more hassle than its worth.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I am also trying to build from source, see here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123260/install-kde-applications-under-gnome. My question there is how to specify `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/your/kde4/install/dir ..`

Comment: @Tim No, no. Rebuild the PPA sources. Basically, install the build dependencies and then `debuild -uc -us`. The result, if the build is successful, will be some debs. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671

Comment: @Tim, updated, basically you should do what Faheem says.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Thanks! It may take me quite a while to understand your reply there, since it is quite long. So which will be more likely to succeed, build from source as in my another post, or rebuild the PPA source as in your another post?

Comment: @Tim, definitely rebuilding the ppa package, many things will have been configured to work nicely with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Graeme:Thanks! I don't  understand unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671 yet due to my limited knowledge. In my case, what steps and commands shall I run to rebuild the ppa package? if possible, can you adapt the approach there to my case?

Comment: @Tim we can talk about it in chat. if you want, ping me in the main unix.sx. chatroom. I think Graeme is also there some of the time.