# Okular doesn't work any more

Tags: okular

Under My Ubuntu 12.04, Okular worke fine  until I recently run apt-get upgrade. Now I can start Okular, but when try to open a pdf file, Okular just flashes and exits.
Here is the output when I run it from the terminal:

```
$ okular 1.pdf
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-42dKIwE1xj,guid=c600816fe140597aecffe6cb0000003d" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-42dKIwE1xj,guid=c600816fe140597aecffe6cb0000003d" 
Registered DEC:  true 
okular(27689)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(27689)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(27689)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(27689)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(27689)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
Registered event listener change listener:  true 
okular: symbol lookup error: okular: undefined symbol: _ZN11KActivities16ResourceInstanceC1EmP7QObject
```

My Okular is installed from https://launchpad.net/~kalakris/+archive/okular, following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123300/674.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the upgrade broke linking for okular. If you still have the setup from the previous question, try rebuilding from the sources. Also, do you know what was upgraded?

Comment: If you still have that directory around, just running `debuild -uc -us` will probably work.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: (1) I uploaded my /var/log/apt/history.log here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/history.log. I installed Okular on April 5th. (2) I still have the deb file generated last time, but I deleted all the source files. Will the deb files help?

Comment: No, you'll need to fetch the sources again, and recompile it as you did before. The deb files are the binaries - basically the same thing as is installed on your system. It won't do you any good. Next time, don't delete the source, you never know when you might need it.

Comment: I still recommend using the [Kubuntu backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports/+index?field.series_filter=precise) instead otherwise you will likely run into the same problem again and have to recompile each time.

Comment: @Faheem: It turns out that after I remove Okular and then dkpg from the deb file I created last time, Okular works again. I wonder how that can be because of some dependencies upgraded?

Comment: @Tim hmm, that's surprising, for me at least. I would have expected that if the ABI broke, you would have to do a recompilation/rebuild. If you are sure your problem is fixed, I recommend a self-answer then, and accept it.